# Error in C++ program (*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000024a1c4f ***)

Tags: c++, algorithm

i'm writing a simple program in C++, however i keep getting the error described in the title. I have searched the internet, but the questions and answers i find usually involve templates. When i run the program on the clang compiler it simply stops without executing the function (marked in the code), but when i ran it on the online gdb debugger i was able to identify the error, however, i don't know what is causing it. I commented the function i think is causing the issue on the code.

Any help is much appreciated!

The code:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include "vector"
#include "algorithm"
#include "utility"
#include "cmath"
class Parser{
private:
  std::vector<char> input_c;
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, char>> assigned_pairs;
  std::vector<double> multi_values;
public:
  void extract_multis(){ /*STOPPED IN THIS FUNCTION */
    for(int i = 0; i < input_c.size(); i++){
      if(get_type(input_c[i-1]) == "multi"){
    std::cout<<input_c[i]<<'\n';
    multi_values.push_back(std::strtod(&input_c[i],NULL));
      }
    }
    for(auto i : multi_values){
    std::cout<<"multi values: "<<i<<'\n';
    }
  }
  std::string get_type(char x){
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, char>>::iterator ll;
    for(ll = assigned_pairs.begin();ll != assigned_pairs.end(); ll++){
      if( ll->second == x){
    return ll->first;
      }
    }
  }
  void show_pairs(){
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, char>>::iterator ll;
    for(ll = assigned_pairs.begin(); ll != assigned_pairs.end();ll ++){
      std::cout<<ll->first<<'\t'<<ll->second<<'\n';
    }
  }
  void define_types(std::vector<char> y){
    for(int i = 0; i < y.size(); i++){
      switch(y[i]){
      case '+':
    assigned_pairs.push_back(std::make_pair("sum",y[i]));
    break;
      case '*':
    assigned_pairs.push_back(std::make_pair("multi",y[i]));
    break;
      case '-':
    assigned_pairs.push_back(std::make_pair("sub",y[i]));
    break;
      case '/':
    assigned_pairs.push_back(std::make_pair("div",y[i]));
      default:
    assigned_pairs.push_back(std::make_pair("term", y[i]));
      }
    }
  }
  void tokenize(std::string x){
    for(auto i : x){
      input_c.push_back(i);
    }
    define_types(input_c);
    show_pairs();
    extract_multis();
  }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  Parser larry;
  const std::string input = "4*3+1+2*5*6";
  larry.tokenize(input);
}
```

Comment: What did you identify as the error when using gdb?

Comment: Do you have compile warnings turned on? `'Parser::get_type': not all control paths return a value` When `i` is 0 `i - 1` is out of range here: `if (get_type(input_c[i - 1]) == "multi")`

Comment: i'm fairly new to programming, so i don't know how to properly use a debugger, when i ran the program on the online gdb console, it gave me the error in title

Comment: You don't need to use a debugger - just compile with the right warnings turned on: https://godbolt.org/z/9o116TTsj  The warning says `In member function 'std::string Parser::get_type(char)':<source>:31:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function` And when you run it, the sanitizer says `READ of size 1 at 0x60200000008f thread T0 #0 0x40a621 in Parser::extract_multis() /app/example.cpp:15` where line 15 is `if(get_type(input_c[i-1]) == "multi"){`

Comment: How to use a debugger: Step through the program and keep a close eye on both the direction the program takes and the values it stores . If you see something unexpected, you just found a bug. That or your expectations are wrong. You can't code worth smurf with bad expectations, so making sure they are right is just as important as writing bug-free code.

Comment: Also worth noting that in `define_types`, one of the cases doesn't have a `break;` Maybe a bug. Maybe not a bug. Haven't really looked at the code too closely.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several bugs in the shown code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < input_c.size(); i++){
  if(get_type(input_c[i-1]) == "multi"){
```

On the first iteration of the loop `i` will be 0, the beginning value. The `if` statement's condition will then try to evaluate `input_c[-1]` which is undefined behavior.

```
  std::string get_type(char x){

       // ...

  }
```

If the loop in this function fails to find a match, and ends, this function reaches an end without returning a `std::string`.

This is also undefined behavior, and all modern C++ compilers will issue a warning about this common programming error. If yours didn't you should consider updating your compiler. If yours did you should always attempt to fix all messages that your compiler is producing, even if the compiler still manages to produce compiled code. Your compiler is reporting a likely bug in the code, like the one here.

These are the obvious bugs in the shown code. There could be less obvious ones, but before getting there you will need to fix these major bugs, first.

Comment: Thanks for the help!